# FilenameFilter, searching for folders

Tags: java, android

I have this class that implements `FilenameFilter`

```
package Logic;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class Filter implements FilenameFilter {

 String name; 

 public Filter(String name) {
    this.name = name; 

 }
 @Override
 public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
    return name.contains("bluetooth");
 }
}
```

I use this class in this method:

```
public String searchForBluetoothFolder() {

    String folderNameToSearchFor = "bluetooth";
    File root = sdCard; 
    FilenameFilter filter = new Filter(folderNameToSearchFor);  

    String[] bluetoothFolder = root.list(filter);

    for(int i = 0; i < bluetoothFolder.length; i++) {
        Log.i("Bluetooth: ", bluetoothFolder[i]); 
    }


    return "";
}
```

Inside the for-loop, the ouput is just **all** of the files in the root directory, not those who have bluetooth as name. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are checking whether `name` contains "bluetooth" and not whether the `fileName` contains the word "bluetooth"

`return name.contains("bluetooth");` should be changed to  `return filename.contains("bluetooth");`

However, by the way you're trying to implement, change it to `return filename.contains(name);` so that you do actually check whether your `fileName` contains the `name` that you've specified.

Also keep in mind that "bluetooth" might not be evaluated the same with `contains()` as "Bluetooth" or "blueTooth". If you want case-insensitive search, then I would suggest to `standardize` your name. Set `name` to lowercase and check using `filename.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())`. Something like:

```
public class Filter implements FilenameFilter {
 String name; 

 public Filter(String name) {
    this.name = name; 

 }
 @Override
 public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
    //If you want to perform a case-insensitive search
    return filename.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method contains in the attribute name, call it in the parameter filename instead. You also should remove the literal string from the method, doing like this:

```
filename.contains(name)
```

This way you are using the attribute that you created for it, and can reuse the class in another cases. The same applies to the searchForBluetoothFolder method.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileFilter folderFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() && file.getName().contains("bluetooth");
    }
};

File[] files = f.listFiles(folderFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package Logic;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class Filter implements FilenameFilter {

 String name; 

 public Filter(String name) {
    this.name = name; 

 }
 @Override
 public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
    return filename.contains("bluetooth");
 }
}
```